# Only execute onEdit if the users make edit within a specific range

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I trigger onEdit only when users make any edits with a specific range in Google App Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create an `onEdit` that only fires when certain cells are edited, but you can put a condition in the beginning of your function to check if the edited cells are part of the range you want to track changes from. You can do that with the use of an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) for that.

For example, you can do this (check inline comments):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // Information from edited range:
  var range = e.range;
  var editedRow = range.getRow();
  var editedCol = range.getColumn();
  var editedSheet = range.getSheet();
  // Range to track (please change accordingly):
  var sheetName = "Sheet To Track";
  var minCol = 3;
  var maxCol = 7;
  var minRow = 2;
  var maxRow = 5;
  // Check that edited sheet, column and row are the ones you want to track changes from:
  if (editedSheet.getName() === sheetName && editedRow >= minRow && editedRow <= maxRow && editedCol >= minCol && editedCol <= maxCol) {
    // Actions to perform if edited range is correct
  }
}
```

The function above will first check if the edited range is (1) between columns 3 and 7, (2) between rows 2 and 5 and (3) in the sheet called `Sheet To Track`.

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects: Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, that's what I was planning to do.